# rails order parameterized query

Tags: sql, ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I know that order is not safe, so I want to refactor this code:

```
@tasks = @search.result.joins(user_application_status: {student_application: [student_profile: :student]})
                       .order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).page(params[:page])
```

`sort_column` is reading from params directly and would be something like `user_application_tasks.name` and `sort_direction` would return somethig like `asc`, I tried refactoring it to:

```
.order("? ?", sort_column, sort_direction).page(page_params)
```

but I am getting an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...HERE (application_statuses.id = 137)  ORDER BY ? ?, user_app...
```

I have done this sort of thing before with where statements like

```
Thing.where("state = ?" ,params[:state])
```

Is there some special syntax I am omitting?

**EDIT:**

The thing I am most worried about is someone being able to inject sql here and do something harmful, as @spickermann mentioned order doesn't sanitize the data so

```
Thing.order("name; drop table users;")
```

will result in the users table being destroyed.

Comment: May be it doesn't work with `order`.

Answer (score 4):

`order` doesn't sanitize attributes when they are provided in a list like `where` does.

But is accepts as hash like this:

```
order(sort_column => sort_direction)
```

See the [Rails Guides About Ordering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering).